# Dropdown materialize não reconhece clique no smartphone no navegador chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, materialize

Tenho uma tabela que possui um dropdown materialize, que quando selecionado pelo PC/Notebook funciona normalmente. Porém quando clicado por algum dispositivo mobile com o mesmo navegador ele não reconhece o touch como click e não direciona para a página específica.
Código do `<th>` da tabela abaixo.

```
    <th>
        <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
        <a class='dropdown-trigger btn' href='#' data-target='status'>Status</a>

        <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
        <ul id='status' class='dropdown-content'>
              <li><a href="@Url.Action("Filtrar","Construcao", new {text = "Não Iniciado"})">Não Iniciado</a></li>
              <li><a href="@Url.Action("Filtrar","Construcao", new {text = "Em Andamento"})">Em Andamento</a></li>
              <li><a href="@Url.Action("Filtrar","Construcao", new {text = "Pausado"})">Pausado</a></li>
              <li><a href="@Url.Action("Filtrar","Construcao", new {text = "Finalizado"})">Finalizado</a></li>
        </ul>
   </th>
```

Estou utilizando jquery para chamar os dropdowns

```
$('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown();
```

Comment: Tentou com @Html.ActionLink() ao invés de @Url.Action()?

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer o seguinte:

**Html**:

```
<div>
    <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
    <div class='btn'>
        <a id="dropdown-trigger" data-target="status" onclick="abreDropdown"> 
            Status
        </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
    <ul id='status' class='dropdown-content'>
          <li><a href="@Url.Action("Filtrar","Construcao", new {text = "Não Iniciado"})">Não Iniciado</a></li>
          <li><a href="@Url.Action("Filtrar","Construcao", new {text = "Em Andamento"})">Em Andamento</a></li>
          <li><a href="@Url.Action("Filtrar","Construcao", new {text = "Pausado"})">Pausado</a></li>
          <li><a href="@Url.Action("Filtrar","Construcao", new {text = "Finalizado"})">Finalizado</a></li>
    </ul>
```

**Javascript**:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let elem = document.getElementById('dropdown-trigger');
  let instances = M.Dropdown.init(elem);
});

function abreDropdown(){
    let elem = document.getElementById('dropdown-trigger')
    M.Sidenav.getInstance(elem).open();
}
```

Tive um problema parecido com o Materialize e o Angular, onde o sistema ignorava o link e insistia em tentar abrir uma nova página.

Comment: Olá, no caso o problema se encontra no clique da ´<li>´ e não em abrir o dropdown em si. É como se a @Url.Action não executasse o link quando há um touch em um dispositivo mobile.

Comment: @Thiagomoreira o que acontece se você substituir a tag `<ul>` por uma `<div>` com as mesmas propriedades e deixar direto a âncora (`<a>`) no lugar dos `<li>`?

Comment: Então eu preciso das <tr> pois é uma tabela. este dropdown está dentro de uma tabela então não posso alterar